# Xamarin forms. Make Masterdetailpage only as high as the children inside

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, margin, screen-size

I want to create a Masterdetailpage that has the same size dependent on which device the app is running. I´ve tried it with a custom renderer, and got the screensize from the device (Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density) and used a Margin nearly half the size of the screen, to match its children. But the Masterdetailpage is longer/higher on an Samsung Galaxy S8 than on and S6.

Is there a better way to get the ScreenHeight? The best way would be to set the Height of the Masterdetailpage equal to the Height of its Children (ListView), but how?

Answer (score 1):

The page has to cover whole the screen, that is how the operating system (Android or iOS) works by definition. Your request in its original form is impossible. You probably need to describe the problem instead of proposing the solution as such solution isn't possible and cannot be built upon.